# Setting page title dynamically in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs6

I have recently upgraded to Angular 6 and rxjs 6, since the upgrade, the following code to set the page title dynamically is no longer working

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map((route) => {
         while (route.firstChild) {
           route = route.firstChild;
         };

         return route;
      })
      .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      .subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));
};
```

This gives me an error

```
this.router.events.filter is not a function
```

I tried wrapping the filter in a pipe like

```
this.router.events
.pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
```

But I get the error

```
this.router.events.pipe(...).map is not a function
```

I have imported the filter like

```
import { filter, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to use [pipeable/lettables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(() => this.activatedRoute),
  map((route) => {
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    };

    return route;
  }),
  filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
  mergeMap((route) => route.data),
).subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Chan, that worked, and thanks again for the link

Answer (score 1):

In RxJs 6 all the operators are pipeable, which means they should be used inside pipe method call. More info about that [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

So the code that you have should become something like:

```
   this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map((route) => {
         while (route.firstChild) {
           route = route.firstChild;
         };

         return route;
      }),
      filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
      mergeMap((route) => route.data)
).subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));
```

If you have a larger app I suggest you have a look at the [rxjs-tslint project](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint) as it will allow you to update automatically the code.

Comment: Thanks @Adraian Faciu, and thanks for extra knowledge you are sharing, : D I needed it.